# What is the difference in using global _main and global _start in the text section of asm

Tags: assembly

I am new at assembly language.
I have been studying it but i am confused between these two: `global _main` and `global _start`..
If anyone knows it, please help!

Comment: One makes `_main` global, the other makes `_start` global. What is the _actual_ problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: There's no difference other than the name of the symbol that been made global.

Comment: One difference may be that some debuggers assume one or the other as a default entry point.

Comment: A short synopsis, when linking without the CRT (C-runtime) library (and C startup files) (e.g. `nasm -felf64 -o foo.obj foo.asm`; `ld -o foo, foo.obj`) `ld` looks for an *entry point* named `_start`. If linking with the CRT, the entry point is `main` (because the CRT provides `_start` on its own, and your path to `_start` when using CRT is through `main`). There are a few caveats, but in a nutshell, without CRT, you provide `_start`, with CRT, you provide `main` because CRT provides `_start` on its own.

Comment: Since you mention `_main` (with an underscore), I'm curious if this is NASM on Windows platform?

Comment: @MichaelPetch it works on both platform(linux & windows).

Comment: are they just the variables declared globally or they are some distinct functions? that's what i want to ask @Michael

Comment: @Moksh : Both are just labels that point to a memory address. In the case of `_start` when it comes to _ELF_ binaries it is the default label used that acts as the address where the program starts. `main` is a label (address) that the _C_ runtime calls when it finished initializing a _C_ program.

Comment: thanks @MichaelPetch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`main` or `_main` or `main_` (OpenWatcom) is known to the C language, and is `call`ed by "startup code" which is "usually" linked to - if you're using C.

`_start` is known to the linker `ld` (in Linux) as the default entrypoint (another symbol can be used) and is not `call`ed. Thus, there is no return address on the stack. Stack starts with number of arguments. Your OS may differ.